# indent lines equally with echo

Tags: bash, shell

I am struggling to cat a file while print it along with some words.

For example:

/root/file contains:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -en "Printing Line of the file: `cat /root/file`\n"
```

Result:

```
Printing Line of the file: line1
 line2
 line3
```

Expected Result:

```
Printing Line of the file:  line1
                            line2
                            line3
```

How can I get the output I want?

Comment: Thanks. But its still printing the same way only. My expectation is to use single space on first line and from second line onwards need to use three tabs

Comment: Is the output format what you positively need? It isn't very easy for humans or computers to read. Something like `echo Printing... ; sed 's/^/    /' /root/file` is easier to code and easier to read its output.

Answer (score 7):

Just bash:

```
( 
    first="Printing Line of the file:"
    IFS=
    read -r line
    printf "%*s %s\n" ${#first} "$first" "$line"
    while read -r line; do 
        printf "%*s %s\n" ${#first} "" "$line"
    done 
) < file
```

```
Printing Line of the file: line1
                           line2
                           line3
```

With printf, you can use `*` as the field width, then provide a number in the arguments. I'm running this in a subshell so altering `IFS` does not affect the parent shell.

---

To achieve your written goal with the tabs:

```
echo "Printing Line of the file: $(awk -v ORS="\n\t\t\t" 1 file)"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use existing utilities like this:

```
myvar="Printing Line of the file:  "
size=${#myvar}
# getting the right size is the tricky part
var_final_size=$((size+5))
echo -en "${myvar}`awk -F\; -v fmt="%${var_final_size}s\n" '{if (NR==1) {print $1} else {printf fmt, $1}}'  test.txt`\n"
```

Or you can script something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
myvar="Printing Line of the file:  "
size=${#myvar}
var_counter=0
for r in  `cat /root/file`
do 
   var_size=${#r}
   var_final_size=$((size+var_size))
   if [ $var_counter -eq 0 ]; then
      printf "%${var_final_size}s\n" "${myvar}${r}"
   else 
      printf "%${var_final_size}s\n" "${r}" 
   fi 
   var_counter=$((var_counter+1))
done
```

Output

```
Printing Line of the file: line1
                           line2
                           line3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo -en "Printing Line: `awk '{if (NR==1) {print " "$0} else {print "\t\t\t"$0}}' file`\n"

Printing Line:  line1
                        line2
                        line3
```

(That seems to work, even though it's nesting " inside "", it might need to be `print \" \"$0` and similar to escape them properly, I don't know).

Answer (score 0):

The following prints line by line -- right justify at 32 characters:

```
awk '{ printf("%32s\n", $0) }'
```

Assuming same length lines... we could peak at first line, count characters and set the pattern for printf on all lines.

```
awk 'NR==1 { f = "%" length "s\n" } { printf(f, $0) }'
```

If lines are not the same length, the same idea can be used with sprintf to create a *pad* of spaces:

```
awk -v x='Printing Line of the file:  ' 'NR==1 { pad = sprintf("%" length(x) "s", ""); print x $0; next } { print pad $0 }' /root/file
```